# Sampling Complexity of Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: statistics, complexity-theory, sampling

What is the computational complexity of sampling from a multivariate normal distribution ?

Does the covariance matrix need to be inverted first, yielding a O(n^3) algorithm 
or there exists algorithms with complexity O(n^2) ?

Comment: Presumably you'd want to generate many random vectors with the given covariance structure, so any decompositions etc would only need to be done just once, in the beginning. Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: I'm planning on using the numpy.random.multivariate_normal function. So, I will indeed need many samples, and the amortized cost is interesting. But I was wandering mostly if I should make sure to sample as much samples as possible each time to amortize the cost. In the case where it is a O(n^2) algorithm, I don't have to worry about that aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *C* is your covariance matrix, and *C=LL<sup>T</sup>* is its Cholesky decomposition, then *Lx* would have the required covariance structure. Here, *x* is an *n*-vector of standard normal variables.

Cholesky decomposition takes O(n^3) time to compute. However, if you do it upfront and then just use *L*, you'll have amortized the cost across all the random samples you compute.

Comment: Looking at the numpy's mtrand.pyx file, you can see that they are using a svd decomposition of complexity O(n^3). The other operations are simply matrix multiplication and additions of complexity O(n^2). Therefore, it worth sampling a big batch for each function call to amortize the cost.